# xmlstarlet with space between results

Tags: xml, xpath, command-line, xmlstarlet

I am using this xmlstarlet command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//path"  -v "dir" -o "" -v "file"
```

on this XML structure

```
<pathlist>
 <path>
  <dir>C:\</dir>
  <file>file1.txt</file>
 </path>
 <path>
  <dir>C:\</dir>
  <file>file2.txt</file>
 </path>
</pathlist>
```

and I get as result:

```
C:\file1.txtC:\file2.txt
```

as one string but without any space between the two path names.
What would be the right xmlstarlet command to still get one string but with a space between the path names like this:

```
C:\file1.txt C:\file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `-o` output switch *after* the `file` XPath, and give it a space rather than an empty string argument:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//path"  -v "dir" -v "file" -o " " in.xml
```

and then you'll get a space after each `file`:

```
C:\file1.txt C:\file2.txt
```

### Update

If you know the number of paths you wish to join into a single string in advance, you can use `concat()`:

```
xml.exe sel -t -v "concat(//path[1]/dir, //path[1]/file, ' ', //path[2]/dir, //path[2]/file)" in.xml
```

Comment: well, i tried that already,but then i get two separate strings.i do use the path names later on in a pscp command. and doing it this way it only copies C:\file1.txt

Comment: the number of paths will be flexible

Comment: Then I suggest that you re-examine how you can take the output of `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//path"  -v "dir" -v "file" -o " " in.xml` and make it work for you.  Bowing out here.  Please learn to save everybody time by avoiding the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Thanks.

Comment: What does "two separate strings" mean?

Comment: the xmlstarlet result is assigned to a shell variable with a loop( like this: `var=$(xmlstarlet ....) ` and when i put a -o "" at the end it just assigns the first path to the shell variable and leaves the loop . when i do it without the -o "" i get both pathes without any space between them

Comment: I would guess the problem is you didn't put quotes around `var` when you used it, i.e. you should use `"$var"`, instead of `$var`.